# Oracle Reports Builder Format Trigger not Working

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

I've added a field based on a formula and I've set the visibility to NO.

Then I've inserted a Format Trigger which returns TRUE if a condition is met.

If condition then return true else return false, but It always seems to be false and the field visibility remains NO.

Field Properties:

[image]

So when the flag is 6661 nothing is displayed neither for other value other than that.

When I tested with the flag set in database to other value than 128 it is correct nothing is displayed, but then I've change the flag to 128 still nothing appears Although value 1 or 2 should be displayed.

Thank you!

Comment: the formula of the calculation of the field 
    fetch c_get_value into flag ;
    if (flag = 6651) then 
     return 'Value 1';
    else 
     return 'Value 2';
    end if;
    
    
    This is the format trigger 
      if xxx_value = 128 then 
       return (TRUE);
      else 
       return (FALSE);
      end if;

Comment: If you can't see it, then it seems that XXX_VALUE isn't 128 (as you expected). I suggest you display XXX_VALUE to see what's really going on.